# Compare arrays in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, common-table-expression

[image]

Above history table captures time and zones where a tag is present at the moment.
I want to find out when a tag enters or exits a zone.
tried with

```
    more_data as (
         select tag_id,
                update_time,
                zone_ids as current_zones,
                lag(zone_ids, 1) over (partition by tag_id order by update_time asc) as prev_zones
         from tag_hist
         order by update_time asc
     )
select *
from more_data
order by tag_id, update_time asc;
```

Now I have
[image]

Now I want to compare current and prev zones to identify entered/exited zones

```
with entered zones = current_zones - prev_zones
with exited zones = prev_zones - current_zones
```

And finally I want to have something like
[image]

try it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a7db2/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that operating on unnested array elements is easier than on whole arrays:

```
with tag_hist_row_numbers as (
-- add row numbers 
    select *, row_number() over (order by tag_id, update_time) as rn
    from tag_hist
),
tag_hist_enter_exit as (
-- unnest zone_ids and find enters/exits
    select 
        tag_id, zone_id, update_time, rn,
        rn - 1 is distinct from lag(rn) over w as enter,
        rn + 1 is distinct from lead(rn) over w as exit
    from tag_hist_row_numbers
    cross join unnest(zone_ids) as zone_id
    window w as (partition by tag_id, zone_id order by update_time)
),
tag_hist_times as (
-- assign enter/exit times
    select 
        tag_id, 
        zone_id, 
        enter,
        update_time as enter_time,
        case when exit then update_time else lead(update_time) over w end as exit_time
    from tag_hist_enter_exit
    where enter or exit
    window w as (order by tag_id, zone_id, update_time)
)
select
-- remove redundant rows
-- rows with exit are useless now
    tag_id, 
    zone_id, 
    enter_time,
    exit_time
from tag_hist_times
where enter
order by tag_id, zone_id
```

[SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a7db2/20)

You can aggregate times into arrays for each `zone_id` if you prefer this format of the final results.

Comment: Thanks a lot @klin it works
Is it possible to return exit time as null or empty when a zone is not exited yet.
To identify that tag is currently in that zones.

Comment: Yes, see [SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a7db2/27) Compare the queries (two changes) to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with below if it resolves what you need,

```
with more_data as (
         select tag_id,
                update_time,
                zone_ids as current_zones,
                lag(zone_ids, 1) over (partition by tag_id order by update_time asc) as prev_zones
         from tag_hist
         order by update_time asc
     )
select t.*,
   (select array(select unnest(current_zones::int[]) except select unnest(prev_zones::int[]))) as "entered zones",
   (select array(select unnest(prev_zones::int[]) except select unnest(current_zones::int[]))) as "exited zones"
from more_data t
order by tag_id, update_time asc;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=84309a6c74456e696021c666c8c1cafa)

Comment: it solves half of my problem, is there any way we can we capture entry exit times also

Comment: @Jebil, I must admit I didn't get the part how the last final output can be derived from the array of `"entered zones"` and `"exited zones"` ? Could you explain ?

Comment: when an id comes in 'entered zones' its entered_at is populated, 

and when it comes in 'exited zones' its exited_at is populated

Comment: @Jebil, thanks for clarification. I got it. However I got new learnings from this post.